# extracting organization name from X509Certificate in android

Tags: android, x509certificate

Hi I want to extract organization name from X509Certificate. For most application i am getting this organization name but for Amazon application I am not able to extract this name because for Amazon app `x509Cert.getIssuerDN().toString();` returns result without ',' between OU O and L value.

I am using following code:

```
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
                X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certStream);
                String temp = x509Cert.getIssuerDN().toString();
```

For other app temp is like:

```
CN=MAP4 Platform 466-1, OU=MDb, O=Motorola, L=Libertyville, ST=Illinois, C=US
CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Google Inc., L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
CN=Microsoft Corporation Third Party Marketplace (Do Not Trust), OU=Android Marketplace Signing for Microsoft Office, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, ST=Washington, C=US
```

Above there is separator (,) between OU,O,L but for amazon app there is no separator following is result of 2 amazon apps:

```
CN=Amazon Self-Sign CA, OU="Java Object Signing O=Amazon Services LLC L=Las Vegas", ST="Nevada C=US"
CN=Amazon Self-Sign CA, OU="Java Object Signing O=Amazon Services LLC L=Las Vegas", ST="Nevada C=US"
```

Now from above result how i will get value of O? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is an error in the DN. The `O` and `L` value inside the `OU`, therefore you don't see a separator (just look at the double quotes which encapsulate the `OU` value).

Comment: @Robert is correct. Indeed, there is no `O` RDN attribute in your X.500 name. The only `O` attribute (textual) is part of `OU` attribute and is not encoded as RDN.

Comment: Error in DN means from Amazon? because I am using same code and for other application its working fine

Comment: Could you attach the certificate in your question?

Comment: Hi @pedrofb. I am extracting organization name from install app. this is the link of application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the certificate does not contain an `O` attribute. It seems that the creator of the certificate made an error and included the content of the  `O` and `L` attributes as part of `OU`

You can check it with OpenSSL. Extract `META-INF/ANDROID.RSA` from apk and execute

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in ANDROIDS.RSA -noout -print_certs -text
```

[image: openssl]

Therefore, to extract the `O` attribute for this certificate, parse the string value of the `OU` attribute and look for "O=[the value]"

Comment: Thanks for reply I just want to confirm creator of the certificate made an error.